# How can I export data in php web page as excel file?

Tags: php, excel

```html
<?php
   include ('PHPExcel.php');
   include ('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
   include ('PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php');
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
     
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

   $worksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'User name');
   $worksheet->setCellValue('B1', 'First name');
   $worksheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Last name');
     
   $excelRow = 2;
      
   $worksheet->setCellValue('A' . $excelRow, 'admin');
   $worksheet->setCellValue('B' . $excelRow, 'testuser');
   $worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $excelRow, 'testuser');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Test.xls');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
   $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit;
?>
```

Hi, I would like to export my data as an excel file with php. I can download file as excel. But I take error in excel like below.
Can you help me to fix the problem? Thank you in advance.

> Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not copy temporary zip file C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Temp\php65EC.tmp to php://output. in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PhpTest\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php:395
>
> Warning  copy(C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Temp\php65EC.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PhpTest\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php

Comment: Well, does that path exist?

Comment: Yes, path exists.

Comment: check folder permissions & 1st try to download from url

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PhpTest\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php file is openable with xampp server. And I looked url of file:///C:/Users/RUMEYSA/AppData/Local/Temp/php65EC.tmp. It is downloaded with browser.

Comment: When I added  $objWriter->save('php://output') to php file, it gives error. Normally, It saves the excel file under xampp directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I writed the code below instead of "$objWriter->save('php://output');". And excel was opened correctly.

```html
$filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/" . rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".tmp";
$objWriter->save($filePath);
readfile($filePath);
unlink($filePath);
```